# Question on negative energy (bound state) in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, conventions

I was going through this [lecture note](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~ldeldebb/docs/QM/lect12.pdf) in 1D harmonic oscillator. And this is a screenshot from it (page 5)

[image]

It says "Hamiltonian can only have positive eigenvalues". So what are bound states? I thought they do have $E<0$, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E < 0$ is meaningless unless you specify what physically corresponds to zero energy; only energy *differences* are physically meaningful.

The correct statement is that a bound state has energy less than the potential energy at spatial infinity. Since the potential energy for a harmonic oscillator becomes arbitrarily large at large distances from the origin, all allowed states are bound states.

Comment: This is from wikipedia article on bound states:
"The potential may be external or it may be the result of the presence of another particle; in the latter case, one can equivalently define a bound state as a state representing two or more particles whose interaction energy exceeds the total energy of each separate particle. One consequence is that, given a potential vanishing at infinity, negative energy states must be bound." What does the last sentence mean in this case? Does negative energy state being bound have a physical meaning?

Comment: @Ufomammut The key phrase is "given a potential vanishing at infinity". That sets the zero of the energy to be the value of the potential energy infinitely far away. The state's energy is negative relative to this zero.

Answer (score 0):

What it means to say is that the energy states cannot be infinitely lowered. If that would be the case the system could radiate an infinite amount of energy. (Since each time the energy state is lowered you could extract some energy out of it.)

Since we postulate that this cannot be the case there must be a lowering operator a for which.

$$a \psi = 0$$

This state does not have to have 0 energy, but it does yields 0 when you try to lower it.

In other words it does not have a 0 eigenvalue for the Hamiltonian H but for lovering operator a.